# Как установить два textview на одном уровне?

Tags: android, textview

Как textview справа установить на одном уровне с нижним textview 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/numberCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NumberCard"
    style="@style/TextNameTitle"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marginLarge"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginLarge"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nameCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="NameCard"
    style="@style/TextNameBody"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/marginLarge"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginLarge"
    android:layout_below="@id/numberCard"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/totalCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TotalCard"
    style="@style/TextNameTitle"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/marginLarge"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/marginLarge"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Эникейщик, правил

Comment: Воткните в середину таблицу (TableLayout).

Comment: @Эникейщик, с атрибутами разметки не получится?

Comment: @АнтонЛялин, в RelativeLayout не знаю можно ли. В ConstraintLayout точно можно или 2 LinearLayout можно использовать

Comment: Кстати, да. Можно ещё горизонтальный линейный использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите атрибут:

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/nameCard"
```

Возможно еще такие (если текст2 меньше текста1 по высоте):

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nameCard"
```

И пропишите `gravity="center"` и `margin`, чтобы выровнять текст.

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой способ решения вашей проблемы с использованием Constraint Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberCard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="NumberCard"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/numberCard">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="NameCard"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalCard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="TotalCard"
            android:textSize="24sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь это помогло :)

P.S. Гугл рекомендует использовать **Constraint Layout**